# Use where clause on TreeView Node

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView where I get nodes to select like this:

```
           var Key= long.Parse(currentRow.Cells["Key"].Value.ToString());

            var currentNode =  tvProjectList.Nodes[0];
            currentNode.ExpandAll();
            var selectedNode = currentNode.FirstNode.LastNode.LastNode;
```

As you can see I select only last Node, but I don't want to select only last node I want to select node where `Tag` equals to my variable `Key`

Something like this:

```
 var selectedNode = currentNode.FirstNode.LastNode.Tag.Where(x => x.Tag == Key);
```

but I can't use Where clause into node.

It says:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension
>   method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I achieve that I want?

Comment: What tree control are you using?

Comment: CellClick @TerryCarmen

Comment: CellClick isn't a control. Are you using the Microsoft TreeView, or Infragistics or a different one?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft TreeView  @TerryCarmen

Answer (score 0):

If you had assigned unique keys and wanted to find the node by key, all you need is:

> mytree.Nodes[0].Find("key_i_am_looking_for",1);

However that's apparently the opposite of what you're looking for. If you actually need to find the node based on the tag value, your only solution would be to start at the root node and recursively examine each node until you find the tag you want.

```
private void RecursiveSearch(TreeNode treeNode)  
{            
   foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)  
   {     
     TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;         
         foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)  
         {  
            if(n.tag.toString().Equals("what you want"))
                 break;
            else                 
                 RecursiveSearch(n);  
         }  
   }
```

}

Comment: Why I only get 1 node into ` var currentNode = tvProjectList.Nodes[0]` but inside it I have  3 more like  my other variable:  `var selectedNode = currentNode.FirstNode.LastNode.LastNode;` There I have 3 more lastNode How can I acces that nodes into foreach?

Comment: The example above stops when it find the first match, however you can remove "break;" and do something else (add your result to a list, print something, etc.). and it will process all the nodes.